# no return value from one C function written for linux, how does c compiler deal with that?

Tags: c

I get one program (written for linux originally). I can't understand the syntax of some functions. The functions have no return value type. 
Let me give one example

```
add_one_point(xx,yy,zz,index)
  float xx,yy,zz;
  int index;
{
 //the implementation 
}
```

In some functions, the implementations don't return any value, but some really return values.
Is this a valid C code? If so, how does c compiler process that?

Thanks in advance!
Jogging

Comment: First: C is a language with its own standard, it does not change from Operative System to Operative System. What might change are libraries and their interface. Second: Are you sure this compile (without warnings)?

Comment: It's a so-called "old-style" function definition. Aside from the "implicit `int`" rule, it uses the abominable practice of not declaring the argument types in the parameter list, but between the function header and body. It's an obsolescent feature, that should never be used in new code, and eliminated in old code whenever possible.

Comment: @Antonio: C does change from implementation to implementation. (1) The C standard is written to be extensible; there are numerous places in it where the behavior must be defined by the implementation, rather than by the standard, and there are numerous places where the standard allows additional code constructions and behaviors. (2) The C standard is not binding upon anybody and does not posses a monopoly on the “C” name. Implementations may define their own behaviors that differ from the standard (e.g. “gnu89”).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hmmm... What about standards?

Comment: @Antonio: What about standards? Good ones are nice. But they are not mandatory. There is no law requiring people to obey the C standard. (E.g., Microsoft does not support C 1999.) Generally, when a good standard is published, developers modify their software toward conformance with the standard, because there are usually benefits toward common behaviors in different software. But that conformance is almost never perfect. There are many commercial and technical reasons to differ. Additional, because the standard is extensible, two implementations may be perfectly conforming but different.

Comment: Thank all of you! The code is not written by me. I try to modify the code in order to follow good practice, however error occurs. The reason is that I assume implicit void. From your discussion I find that the rule is implicit int. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I have another question. C allows you call one function without providing the declaration of the function in the c source file. Will C compiler  assume the function will return an int value? If the definition of the function return void, do this will cause one problem?

Comment: This question deserves a positive rating after all the edits.

Answer (score 4):

Older versions of C allowed the return type to be omitted, defaulting it to `int`.

C99 no longer allows it, so if you compiled under C99 mode, it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a function not returning any value as returning `void`, and in any case the return type should be specified. Your compiler might allow you to compiler a function without return value specified (it will default to int, that is why that code might be/have been working), but a modern compiler will at least issue a warning.

Furthermore, as somebody else already noticed, also the input types are specified in an unusual way (without verifying, I would call it non-standard compliant)

Comment: But the OP says "some really return values" and is asking how that works.  Declaring as `void` would prevent that.

Comment: The question is "how does c compiler deals with that"

Comment: When talking about something being "standard compliant" you might also mention which standard you assume. I see nothing wrong with the code that's posted in the question. It's perfectly legal in older versions of C.

Comment: @Art I admit not going in the detail of the standard, but in my answer it's clear the distinction between old and new compilers.